# Python: can __file__ be None if import has succeeded?

Tags: python, import

I am working on Python 2.6/2.7 code which contains the following:

```
try:
    import gmpy
    gmpy_imported=True
except ImportError:
    gmpy_imported=False

if gmpy_imported and gmpy.__file__ is None:
    gmpy_imported=False
```

I can understand the `try-except` part, which is used to see if gmpy has been installed on the system -- and if not, to do whatever. However, I do not understand why the `if gmpy.__file__ is None` check is necessary; it seems redundant.

Are there any circumstances when importing a package would appear to have succeeded, but the path to the package would in fact be empty? Is this double-check a failsafe against a corrupted installation?

Comment: If this is Python 3.2+, the import-related code is actually readable enough that we could probably go through it and see if such a thing could ever happen. But I don't think I'd want to try that with the old code…

Comment: Nope, it's Python 2. I should have clarified this in the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in this check. If the module/package had been successfully been imported, `__file__` would never be none, it'd be the path of the module.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too... I'll spend some more time on this, issue, though, because I'd like to know more.

Answer (score 2):

The docs say "The `__file__`attribute is not present for C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter", so I believe it's redundant. Beside, what difference would it make, the module object is there.

Comment: "not present" is not the same as `None`.

Comment: @interjay: True. Given that, the docs define no case where it would be present and set to `None` -- which bolsters my claim that it's redundant.

Comment: +1. But if the docs seem to say that this should never happen, and yet someone has written the code… how do we know that it _isn't_, e.g., to "double-check a failsafe against a corrupted installation", as the OP suggested, without reading the import code (or trying to come up with a test suite, or guessing based on what we know about the knowledge of the person who wrote the OP's code, or…)?

Comment: @abarnert: Short of reading the interpreter's code or being able to read minds, unless it in the documentation, the best we can do is guess about why the test is there -- which are all part of the reason I wrote "I believe" in my answer.

Comment: @martineau: And that's part of the reason I +1'd your answer, too. But the OP is working on someone else's code… which means he might be able to ask the original author, or it might be code from some well-known book or website, or he might know it was written by a guy who knows less Python than he does, or… In other words, there _might_ be more information to go on, making the question answerable.

Comment: According to docs: "`__file__` is set to the name provided by the module loader. If the loader does not make filename information available, this variable is set to None."

Comment: I'm 99% sure who wrote the code and I could ask the person, but he's not on this project anymore; he's busy with other work, and I've already pestered him enough. Also, redundancy is an issue with the entire project, so 2 lines aren't much of a deal... I'll leave it there if I don't figure it out soon but it would be nice to know what's going on there.

Comment: @Boris: You can always add a `# TODO: Find out if this solves a problem, or is just unnecessary code`, so that whoever takes over after you can track you down to ask you to track down the previous guy and eventually give up and add a further comment after he gives up trying to get an answer. :)

Comment: @abarnert: Why not, the codebase already has thousands of those from years and years back :) I'm afraid I'd like to break the chain, but I do admit: it would have been hilarious to talk to my successor on this thread :)